# Best way to implant Facebook in Android application

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to implant Facebook in my app. I tried using the official SDK,but got stuck trying To get the hesh key.

I also tried it with FBRocket, but their example just didn't work.It failed to get past the login.

Is there a better way of doing that? Could someone who had managed it please explain how, maybe showing some code?

Thanks!

Comment: I bet Facebook has sample code that you can look at.

Comment: They do and I have checked it out, but I'm trying To figure how to get the hesh key for 2 days now.

Comment: I *strongly* encourage you to read up on the oAuth protocol (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and *understand* it *before* writing code to access it.

Comment: Well, for now I'm just trying to get past the generation of the hesh key part, I didn't even write any code yet. I'm having problems with openSSL commands.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep trying the adroid-facebook-sdk, as it seems the most up to date library. In what part did you get stuck?

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64
```

Make sure you undersand android signing first: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

---

There are a few blogs/guides out there with step by step procedures to get up and running:

http://twinrainbo.blogspot.com/2010/11/official-facebook-sdk-for-android.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-androidfacebookapi/index.html